# select all maximum values of every 10 minutes timespan of all days in database

Tags: php, mysql

I hav a question how to do such:

I have my Solar-production stored in my own mysql-database

```
table Solar
+-----+------------+----------+------+
| ID  | Datum      | TIME     | Wh   |
+-----+------------+----------+------+
|  16 | 2022-05-22 | 05:49:31 |    1 |
|  17 | 2022-05-22 | 05:59:32 |    1 |
|  18 | 2022-05-22 | 06:09:34 |    1 |
|  19 | 2022-05-22 | 06:19:36 |    1 |
|  20 | 2022-05-22 | 06:29:38 |    2 |
|  21 | 2022-05-22 | 06:39:40 |    5 |
|  22 | 2022-05-22 | 06:50:32 |    6 |
|  23 | 2022-05-22 | 07:00:34 |    6 |
...
| 116 | 2022-05-23 | 05:56:29 |    1 |
| 117 | 2022-05-23 | 06:06:30 |    1 |
| 118 | 2022-05-23 | 06:16:32 |    1 |
| 119 | 2022-05-23 | 06:31:27 |    5 |
| 120 | 2022-05-23 | 06:41:28 |    5 |
| 121 | 2022-05-23 | 06:51:29 |    6 |
| 122 | 2022-05-23 | 07:01:31 |    7 |
...
| 201 | 2022-05-24 | 06:01:54 |    1 |
| 202 | 2022-05-24 | 06:11:56 |    1 |
| 203 | 2022-05-24 | 06:21:57 |    2 |
| 204 | 2022-05-24 | 06:31:59 |    1 |
| 205 | 2022-05-24 | 06:42:01 |    2 |
| 206 | 2022-05-24 | 06:52:02 |    3 |
| 207 | 2022-05-24 | 07:02:05 |    4 |
```

and so on

I want to built a 'reference curve with a chart of the maximum values of each timestep per day.

You see, that the values appear in about 10 min interval, but not precisely.

If I want to have the maximum value of al values in an timerange of 07:00:00 to 07:10:00, then 07:10:00 to 07:20:00 ans so on, i can create a chart of the 'optimal'-reference.

How I can manage to search this result for the maximum value and store this value including the time to a new array?
Is it possible to iterate this query through the whole timespan of a day?

maybe this is not ideal to perform such a query with every call of a php.
How to generate or update a 'reference-database' on a dayly cron?

I hope my questions are clear to you.

Thank you in advance.

Micha

**EDIT1:**

Hi ysth,

I got managed to get the max value of an specific timerange with this:

```
SELECT * from Solar where Time between "06:00:00" and "06:10:00" Order by Wh desc limit 1;
+----+------------+----------+------+
| ID | Datum      | TIME     | Wh   |
+----+------------+----------+------+
| 18 | 2022-05-22 | 06:09:34 |    1 |
+----+------------+----------+------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)
```

manually I did a couple of lines for example:

```
| 564 | 2022-05-28 | 06:10:39 |    2 |
|  20 | 2022-05-22 | 06:29:38 |    2 |
| 385 | 2022-05-26 | 06:31:51 |    6 |
| 120 | 2022-05-23 | 06:41:28 |    5 |
|  22 | 2022-05-22 | 06:50:32 |    6 |
| 122 | 2022-05-23 | 07:01:31 |    7 |
| 123 | 2022-05-23 | 07:11:32 |    8 |
| 124 | 2022-05-23 | 07:21:34 |    9 |
| 125 | 2022-05-23 | 07:31:36 |   10 |
| 126 | 2022-05-23 | 07:41:37 |   11 |
| 127 | 2022-05-23 | 07:51:39 |   13 |
| 128 | 2022-05-23 | 08:01:41 |   15 |
| 129 | 2022-05-23 | 08:11:42 |   17 |
| 396 | 2022-05-26 | 08:22:11 |   18 |
| 397 | 2022-05-26 | 08:32:13 |   19 |
| 132 | 2022-05-23 | 08:41:47 |   21 |
| 400 | 2022-05-26 | 09:02:19 |   23 |
| 401 | 2022-05-26 | 09:12:21 |   28 |
| 489 | 2022-05-27 | 09:24:06 |   32 |
|  38 | 2022-05-22 | 09:31:03 |   35 |
| 585 | 2022-05-28 | 09:41:24 |   39 |
| 139 | 2022-05-23 | 09:51:58 |   46 |
```

this I want for output.

I'm pretty sure I'll have to loop mysql-queries. but this to more simple Times. Here I'm stuck.

I'm not sure jet how I'm supposed to throw this together with the values of another query:

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(CONCAT_WS(' ', Datum, Time)) AS datetime, Wh
        FROM Solar
        WHERE Datum='".$date_sel."'
        ORDER BY 'ID'
        ;

--> 
+-------------------+------+
| datetime          | Wh   |
+-------------------+------+
| 1653623616.000000 |    1 |
| 1653624217.000000 |    1 |
| 1653624819.000000 |    2 |
| 1653625868.000000 |    6 |
| 1653626473.000000 |    5 |
| 1653627083.000000 |    5 |
| 1653627685.000000 |    5 |
| 1653628286.000000 |    6 |
```

[...]

in order to get thes two graph's joined in one chart.
but this is another day's work.

Thank you for answering!

Comment: what does `select version();` show?

Comment: please show an example of the output you want.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks for watching!

mysql> select version();
+-------------------------+
| version()               |
+-------------------------+
| 8.0.29-0ubuntu0.20.04.3 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

Comment: Commenting is not that easy ... I'll try.

my comment is too long, I'll edit my own question.